# Other files overriding my template css with bootstrap?

Tags: css, bootstrap

I have a strange problem with one of my homepages. I changed the `font-family` and `font-size` in my Joomla Template (JM Guesthouse by Joomla Monster) and nothing happened.

After some minutes playing with the development tool, I discovered that something is loading the bootstrap.min.css file and this is overriding the CSS of my template.

After some investigating the backend, I discovered that the Breezing Form that I implement via a module and iframe is loading this file.

Also, the Googlemap that I implement with an iframe is loading this file as well.

After I disabled both, the CSS works correctly.

I would really like to use both on my homepage. How can I enable all of these processes and preserve my template's css declarations?

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap does not use `!important` in its CSS font declarations, therefore the CSS file where you have declared your fonts must be getting loaded *before* Bootstrap CSS. I have no knowledge of Joomla Monster templates; but with most template developers, there is usually a "custom" CSS file for this purpose. [Joomla-Monster Documentation](https://www.joomla-monster.com/documentation/template-tutorials/how-to-add-your-own-css-styles-to-joomla-template-based-on-ef4-framework). Otherwise, you could always declare your fonts using `!important`, e.g.

```
font-family: YourFont, sans-serif !important;
```

Remember to declare suitable fallback fonts in case `YourFont` fails to be parsed by the browser.